# Nunit & resharper test runner. How to get if the test is debugged or run

Tags: nunit, test-runner

When I finished implementation of the new functionality & implemented new automation test I would like to run all test locally. It takes lots of time. Depending if this is run or debug I would like to use different web driver.
How may I check if this is run or debug? I use nunit & resharper test runner.

Comment: Thanks to all I found 
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached